# Mailchimp: Possible to BLOCK a subscriber email (so they can't sign up again)?

Tags: blacklist, mailchimp

Believe it or not, but we have an abusive subscriber on our Mailchimp mailing list who's sending replies to our campaign emails with abusive and unwanted emails back to us.

I've tried to look around in Mailchimp settings but I can't see any way to do this.

It would be good to document it here if there is a solution, so others Googling in the future can find a quick answer, right here.

Can you **block** or blacklist an email address so that it won't be allowed to RE-subscribe to the mailing list later, if they wanted to?

Answer (score 4):

If you just unsubscribe that user, the user can re-subscribe again and receive your emails. I suggest creating a new segment called "Blacklisted" or similar and add unwanted users to that segment (not list, but segment). When you want to send a new email blast you can set to send it to all users except for the Segment name "Blacklisted".

Answer (score 1):

You can go on Listst/ Manage Contacts/ Click unsubscribe - That takes this Email / contact to the unsubscribe list which is what you are looking for. Mailchimp won't send emails to unsubscribed emails